# how can I write code that reacts to a document being disconnected/emoved from a mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a list of blocks in a blockchain and I want to make it so that if a certain collection is disconnected and then reconnects, it reconnects with a block of the latest index.

Comment: The phrase "collection is disconnected" doesn't make sense, especially in the context of the title.

Comment: You can use MongoDB change streams with the Go driver if you want to actively react to document changes, but I agree with the other comment that your description doesn't make much sense in comparison to the title.